# How to group a datatable into a single line of data

Tags: c#, datatable, grouping

Let's say I have the following datatable:

```
EquipmentID    SerialNum  filename
-----------    ---------  --------
441573         05-335-03  2041165.JPG
441573         05-335-03  2041166.JPG
441573         05-335-03  2041167.JPG
441193         52005088   2536398.JPG
```

I want to group this data in a way where 441573 is a single data instance with an array (or list) of filenames.  So the data in the end should look like this:

```
{EquipmentID: 441573, SerialNum: 05-335-03, filename:{2041165.JPG, 2041166.JPG, 2041167.JPG}},

{EquipmentID: 441193, SerialNum: 52005088, filename:{2536398.JPG}}
```

I tried this:

```
var groupedEquipment = from e in equipment.AsEnumerable()
                group e by e.Field<int>("EquipmentID");
```

but that brings back a line for each filename.  I want the filenames grouped within the EquipmentID data as shown.

Any ideas?  The question was probably asked the wrong way, didn't know how I was going to word it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you `GroupBy` your data you can use regular linq functions to select whatever you need. In your case a good example would be using `string.Join` to get a single `string` back so you can write it to the Console.

The `x.Select(y => y.FileName)` line is where the magic comes from. That's the line that selects all items *in the group* and performs some operation on them.

```
class EqupimentEntry
{
    public int EqupimentId { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

```
List<EqupimentEntry> entries = new List<EqupimentEntry>()
{
    new EqupimentEntry { EqupimentId = 441573, SerialNumber = "05-335-03", FileName = "2041165.JPG" },
    new EqupimentEntry { EqupimentId = 441573, SerialNumber = "05-335-03", FileName = "2041166.JPG" },
    new EqupimentEntry { EqupimentId = 441573, SerialNumber = "05-335-03", FileName = "2041167.JPG" },
    new EqupimentEntry { EqupimentId = 441193, SerialNumber = "52005088", FileName = "2536398.JPG" },
};

var groupedEquipments = entries
    .GroupBy(x => x.EqupimentId) //group by the Id
    .Select(x => new //make an anonymous type to get data
    {
        EqupimentId = x.Key,
        //this line will take all FileNames in the group and put a ", " between them.
        //this returns a single string
        FileNameList = string.Join(", ", x.Select(y => y.FileName))
    });

//foreach group, write to console (for example)
foreach (var group in groupedEquipments)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(group.EqupimentId + ":" + group.FileNameList);
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
441573:2041165.JPG, 2041166.JPG, 2041167.JPG
441193:2536398.JPG
```

Note: this example only groups by `EquipmentId`. You can add multiple `GroupBy` elements if needed and those will be accessible from the `Key` property in later methods.

Answer (score 1):

I would use more simplicity using just Linq.

```
  var groupedEquipment = s
     .GroupBy(i => new { i.EquipmentID, i.SerialNum })
     .Select(d => new
     {
         EquipmentID = d.Key.EquipmentID,
         SerialNum = d.Key.SerialNum,
         filename = s.Where(e => e.EquipmentID == d.Key.EquipmentID)
                     .Select(f => f.filename).ToList()                                                 
     }).ToList();
```

First group by EquipmentID and SerialNum, then return all columns in a new selection object to return the resuts

```
{EquipmentID: 441573, SerialNum: 05-335-03, filename:{2041165.JPG, 2041166.JPG, 2041167.JPG}},
{EquipmentID: 441193, SerialNum: 52005088, filename:{2536398.JPG}}
```